# python: forcing relative imports to search from script file

Tags: python, import

This is my directory structure:

```
scripts/
  bpydata/
  bpymodules/
  myCustomScripts/
     lib/
        __init__.py
        customLib.py
     plugin/
        __init__.py
        myParser.py
     __init__.py
     runner.py
  ...
  my_import_script.py
  ...
```

I start with my_import_script, which will import the myCustomScripts package.

From there, I import runner, which will import myParser.

myParser requires something that is defined in customLib, so it will use relative import to get it as such

`from .lib import customLib`

But it doesn't work because I started with my_import_script so it will search its parent directory rather than search myParser's parent directory.

When myParser wants .lib, how can I make sure that I am stepping up one directory from myParser's directory rather than my_import_script's directory?

Comment: Are you executing or importing runner? Those are two different things.

Comment: You're right, it should be importing and not executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import from a parent package use `..`. If I'm not misunderstanding you, this should work:

```
from ..lib import customLib
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: @Keikoku, I'm glad. They work similarly to how you specify relative paths in URLs, shells, and other environments.